# Scrapy data selection

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to scrap data from this plain text :

```
 "data": [
      {
         "id": "10150635906994798_21377910",
         "from": {
            "id": "100001249878256",
            "location" : "Stockholm"
            "name": "Mouhamadoul Moussa"
         },
         "message": "#Yeaaaahh!!! \u2665",

      },
      {
         "id": "10150635906994798_21392047",
         "from": {
             "id": "100000648164454",
              "location" : "Malmo"
            "name": "mallow ty"
         },
         "message": "droit au butttttttttttttttttt",
      },
    ]
```

but I would like to retrieve only second id, xpath for id selection 
`response.selector.xpath ('//*[contains(text(), "id")]')`

Output should be :

```
 100000648164454
 100001249878256
```

Comment: That's `JSON`, not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a plain text ! that's a json. However, you can store it as a dictionary:

```
>>> a = {'data': [{'from': {'id': '100001249878256',
...     'location': 'Stockholm',
...     'name': 'Mouhamadoul Moussa'},
...    'id': '10150635906994798_21377910',
...    'message': '#Yeaaaahh!!! \\u2665'},
...   {'from': {'id': '100000648164454', 'location': 'Malmo', 'name': 'mallow ty'},
...    'id': '10150635906994798_21392047',
...    'message': 'droit au butttttttttttttttttt'}]}

>>> for data in a['data']:
...     print data['from']['id']
... 
100001249878256
100000648164454
```